# Trouble integrating AIRKinect NativeExtension into project, -extdir directory error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, kinect

I'm trying to create a demo project using the [AIRKinect](http://www.as3nui.com/) NativeExtension. I'm using Flex 4.6, AIR 3.1 building in FDT5 on Mac OSX 10.6.8

I've installed everything in the ReadMe (from the [release code on GitHub](https://github.com/AS3NUI)) and tried to use the instructions from [this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html) to get the NativeExtension working in my AIR project.

When I try to run the ADL after successfully compiling the swf, I get an error from the -extdir parameter:

> The -extdir argument must specify an existing directory

I've tried a path to the directory containing the unzipped .ane and the unzipped .ane itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am at the exact same point as you with attempting to get this working.

After contacting PowerFlasher, there is currently no support for native extensions for desktop in FDT 5.  It will be introduced in version 5.1

http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2504

Comment: Frustratingly there seem to be problems with Flex 4.6 and FDT as well.